# Replace Function of Python Not Working in a For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a very basic case where I am lost a bit. I have products_master as series and want to iterate one by one to find and replace these entries in some other dataframe column. It works well if I do it separately but not in the for loop.

```
temp = df[1] 
for j in range (0, len(products_master)):
    temp['Product_Name'].replace(products_master[j], 'PROD' + str(j))
```

Any quick ideas?

Best,
Atamert

Comment: Can you mention what error you're getting?

Comment: you're generating the new string, but you're not saving it anywhere, I believe :)

Comment: yes you were right, I thought that replaces and saves directly

Comment: check if there's a `inplace` parameter somwhere, if there's one then you can use that syntax to achieve what you want

Comment: yes with inline = True it works too! Great advice, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

this solved the issue

```
 temp = df[1] 
 for j in range (0, len(products_master)):
        temp['Product_Name'] = temp['Product_Name'].replace({products_master[j] : 'PROD' + str(j)})
```